# Disambiguating the [congruences] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The tags [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences) and [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic) seem to cover similar ground (judging from the questions which have them).

However, the former can also be misunderstood as talking about the general *congruence relation* (i.e. a relation $R$ such that $aRb$ and $cRd$ imply $(a\circ c)R(b\circ d)$ with respect to some binary operation $\circ$).

As Willie Wong points out in the comments, there's also the "congruence" of triangles from Euclidean geometry.

---

Therefore, in the interest of descriptive tagging, I propose to:

1. Retag those questions in [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences) which are about modular equations with [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic). A synonym for [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic) mentioning "congruence" would be needed -- avoiding the current pitfall;
2. Retag the ones about congruence relations with [congruence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruence-relations) (if they exist -- I didn't check);
3. Retag the ones about triangles with [euclidean-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euclidean-geometry) and/or a new tag, e.g. [geometric-congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-congruence);
4. Perhaps blacklist [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences).

Comment: Some of the questions are about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29 ; they need to be separately retagged. Also, technically the $\pmod p$ congruences are a special type of congruence-relations.

Comment: @WillieWong Ooh, hadn't thought of that (I'm a very algebraic person I guess :)). I know $\pmod p$ is a special case of congruence-relations, but in the current schema it's too easy to confuse the general and the particular.

Comment: Do [polynomial congruences](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=congruence+polynomial) fall under ([tag:modular-arithmetic])? At the moment, there are 3 questions tagged [congruences+polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences+polynomials).

Comment: (By polynomial congruences I meant something like $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{x^2-1}$, i.e. congruences in the rings of polynomials.)

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be considerable support for taking on this tag (+8/-0), which is "high", for questions about tagging).

This answer intends to poll the specific approach I suggested.

Concretely, I suggest to:

- Introduce [congruences-and-remainders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences-and-remainders) as a synonym for [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic);
- Create a [congruence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruence-relations) synonym of [equivalence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equivalence-relations);
- Create a [geometric-congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-congruence) or [geometric-congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-congruences) synonym for [euclidean-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euclidean-geometry) (I'm not knowledgeable in this area, so I hope someone else can provide a better tag name$^\dagger$);
- Blacklist [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences).

---

$^\dagger$: Martin Sleziak suggested [congruences-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences-geometry) [in the Tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11944782#11944782).

Comment: Note that 'congruences-and-remainders' has 26 characters, which is 1 too much. I have suggested 'congruences-remainders' [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19385/43288).

Answer (score 4):

It is too soon to say what is the consensus on this. (Only two people voted on the question.) But I thought that it would be good to be prepared for dividing the tags into several tags by making a list of questions that need to be retagged. It seems that this list is very short. (Of course, I could have missed some questions.) I am making this post CW, feel free to edit it, if needed.

**Congruences in geometry**

(ordered by id)

- [Parallelograms in triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500426/parallelograms-in-triangles)
- [Proof for Symmetry property of Congruent Segments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504394/proof-for-symmetry-property-of-congruent-segments)
- [Why is SSS criterion for congruence of triangles referred to as "SSS postulate" in textbooks?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533459/why-is-sss-criterion-for-congruence-of-triangles-referred-to-as-sss-postulate)
- [Integer-sided isosceles triangle with area equal to $120$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668213/the-second-triangle)
- [Two touching circles inscribed in an angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758961/two-touching-circles-inscribed-in-an-angle)
- [Perpendicular versus perpendicular bisector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764384/prependicular-vs-prependicular-bisector)
- [Congruency in bow-tie triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783227/congruency-in-bow-tie-triangles)
- [Prove two triangles are congruent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920396/triangle-congruence)
- [What is the difference between congruency and equality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915914/what-is-the-difference-between-congruent-and-equal)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047606/question-corresponding-parts-of-congruent-triangles

**Congruence relations**

We have some questions about congruence relations in the sense of universal algebra. (Probably many hits from the search for [congruence relation universal algebra site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=congruence+relation+universal+algebra+site:math.stackexchange.com) are such questions.) <s>But I did not find any such questions among the questions currently tagged [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences).</s> Here are questions which I found among questions tagged [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences):

(ordered by id)

- [Subdirect embedding of a quotient algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671097/subdirect-embedding-of-a-quotient-algebra)
- <s>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663857/abelian-groups-have-the-cep</s> (This question was deleted in the meantime. Although there is a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/cep-for-abelian-groups-and-lattices), which is not tagged (congruences).)
- [Factor congruences of non trivial Lattices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753116/factor-congruences-of-non-trivial-lattices)
- [Congruence lattice of $N_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755069/congruence-lattice-of-n5)
- Maybe [What is the interpretation of $a \equiv b$ mod $H$ in group theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849071/what-is-the-interpretation-of-a-equiv-b-mod-h-in-group-theory) (Although this question is asking, among other things, about the relation of congruences in groups to congruences as used in number theory.)

**Congruences of polynomials**

(ordered by id)

- [Need hints on the following algebra problems.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581934/need-hints-on-the-following-algebra-problems)
- [What is the congruence class of $x^3\mod x^3+x+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585074/what-is-the-congruence-class-of-x3-mod-x3x1)
- [How to find all the roots in this ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650912/how-to-find-all-the-roots-in-this-ring)

**[Matrix congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence):**

(ordered by id)

- [Is every skew-symmetric matrix congruent to a diagonal matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790186/does-any-skew-symmetric-matrix-is-congruences-to-a-diagonal-matrix)
- [Diagonalizing a bilinear form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791422/diagonalizng-a-bilinear-form)

**Not sure**

- <s>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528525/congruence-of-rational-approximations</s> (This question was deleted in the meantime.)

---

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that in the meantime the tag congruences [has also a tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/552523/revisions) (it was created after this discussion on meta was started):

> For question about the properties or calculation of congruences and congruences equation, and related theorems of congruences like chinese remainder theorem, Fermat's little theorem and Euler's totient theorem.

Comment: Those special cases have been retagged in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether I like having [congruence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruence-relations) synonym of [equivalence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equivalence-relations) (as suggested by Lord_Farin.) So here is an alternative suggestion

- Create a [congruence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruence-relations) and keep it as a separate tag or make it a synonym of [universal-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-algebra).
- Make [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences) a synonym of [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic). (This is the most frequent use of this tag so far.)
- Create [congruences-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences-geometry) and keep it as a separate tag (or, if it is not suitable as a standalone tag, make it a synonym of [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry).
- If needed, we can also create [congruences-polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences-polynomials). (Which would be for questions about congruences in rings of polynomials, for example *How to find $u(x)$ such that $u(x)\cdot (x+1) \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+x+1}$ holds in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$.* Not for questions about modular arithmetic where one side of the congruence is a polynomial. For example *How to show that $x\equiv y \pmod n$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) \equiv f(y) \pmod n$, where $f$ is a polynomial with integer coeffcients?*)

Answer (score 1):

In practice, congruences tag is already an equivalent of modular-arithmetic.

---

I found only $6$ questions with the words "congruence relation" that are not about modular arithmetic or equivalence relations, subjects that already have several tags.

*is:q "congruence relation" -[modular-arithmetic] -[number-theory] -[elementary-number-theory]*
https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22congruence+relation%22+-%5Bmodular-arithmetic%5D+-%5Bnumber-theory%5D+-%5Belementary-number-theory%5D

The added expressive power of a new tag beyond [universal-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-algebra), [lattice-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lattice-theory), or [category-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory), which do appear on the existing congruence relation questions, is small.

---

For geometric congruences, there are only 3 (of 78) geometry questions in   [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences), identifiable by clicking on all the non-number theoretic secondary tags like

geometry
triangle
homework
proof-strategy

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences

---

Comment: The very point of this thread is to make the observation that it is "practically" an equivalent official by taking it all the way. That there are few questions that need to be retagged for this is only good. I plainly disagree on the assessment of [tag:congruence-relations].

Comment: Yes, but there is a choice of whether 'all the way' means removing one duplicative tag (blacklist/synonym/merge of congruences with modular-arithmetic) or replacing it by three duplicative tags.  Congruences in geometry are arguably the same thing as euclidean-geometry (they are the morphisms in that category). I would guess that most mathematicians have never encountered the axioms for a congruence relation (as a named concept distinct from equivalence relation), and many would not consider it distinct after having seen the definition!

Comment: It is not relevant (at least to me) how many synonyms a tag has. The only thing I'd like to avoid with this scheme is wrong tagging. Letting a tag sit around that has multiple, unrelated interpretations is simply bad. Do you have an alternative solution for that?

Comment: Your proposal but with synonyms for all three interpretations instead of one plus two new tags.  Such as (congruence[geometry]) --> (euclidean-geometry) and (congruence-relations) --> (equivalence-relations).

Comment: Some reading and thinking have won me over. I've edited my proposal according to your suggestions.